# Microsoft.Graph.API gives Code: generalException Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Microsoft.graph.API for getting OneDrive user data.

I registered my application through Azure AD v2.0 and got access token and refersh token also successfully. But when I am trying to access impersonated user through Admin credential that time i am getting following exception:

Code: generalException Message: Unexpected exception returned from the service.

In this inner exception is null.

Thank you.

c#-4.0

Thank you.